# Add degree symbol (°) to axis labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, axis

I want to add the degree symbol (°) to the labels on my y-axis (not the axis title). I have a ranking on that axis, with numbers ranging 1-11, and I want each of them to say, for example, "1°" instead of just "1". Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first inclination is to look into expressions and `plotmath`-like things, but in this case we can simply add the degree symbol to the text.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, cyl)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = ~ paste0(.x, "°"))
```

[image: ggplot with degree in y-axis labels]

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `bquote` with the `degree` sign by creating it as an `expression` for each label with `sapply` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = x)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = ~as.expression(sapply(.x, \(x) bquote(.(x)~degree))))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Fake** data:

```
df = data.frame(x = c(1:11),
                y = c(1:11))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the unicode symbol for degree, e.g.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, cyl)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = ~ paste0(.x, "\u00B0"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>